# Credit Card Transaction Classification in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm curious to see if anyone has any thoughts on how to accomplish this in Python with Pandas.

I have a dataframe (df1) with the credit card transaction details that contains the Point of Sale description (df1['Description']) and amount (df1['amount']). The POS description is unique to each location so you end up with several descriptions for Amazon, Shell Oil, etc.

I have another dataframe (df_lookup) that will serve as a lookup table to classify the transactions. This dataframe will include the name (df_lookup['Name']) and the category to classify each transaction df_lookup['Category']).

This is what I would like to accomplish:
Compare the df1['Description'] to df_lookup['Name']. If the df1['Description'] contains the df_lookup['Name'], the corresponding df_lookup['Category'] will be added to df1 as a new column df1['Category']. Please see the examples of each dataframe and the desired outcome below.

Example of df1:

| Description | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja AMZN.COM | 10 |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 15 |
| AMZN Prime *an9adjah | 20 |
| Shell Oil 4106541031 | 20 |
| Shell Oil 4163046510 | 25 |

Example of df_lookup:

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| AMAZON | Amazon |
| AMZN | Amazon |
| Shell Oil | Gas |

Desired Output to df1:

| Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja AMZN.COM | 10 | Amazon |
| AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf | 15 | Amazon |
| AMZN Prime *an9adjah | 20 | Amazon |
| Shell Oil 4106541031 | 20 | Gas |
| Shell Oil 4163046510 | 25 | Gas |

Comment: not to be rude but u spelled category wrong in your last DataFrame

Comment: lol, words are hard! thanks

Comment: yw pardner @bbalch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution but it could probably take long time for large DataFrames:

```
def func(x):
    global df_lookup
    for i in df_lookup['Name'].values:
        if i in x:
            return df_lookup.loc[df_lookup['Name'] == i, 'Category'].values[0]
    df_lookup = df_lookup.append({'Name': x, 'Category': 'Needs Category'}, ignore_index=True)
    return 'Needs Category'

df1['Category'] = df1['Description'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

If you have Data for which there is no category in `df_lookup`, e.g. `GOOGLE 5555555555`, then you would get the following outputs.

output for `df1`:

```
                     Description  Amount        Category
0  AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja AMZN.COM      10          Amazon
1          AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf      15          Amazon
2           AMZN Prime *an9adjah      20          Amazon
3           Shell Oil 4106541031      20             Gas
4           Shell Oil 4163046510      25             Gas
5                 GOOGLE 5555555      10  Needs Category
```

output for `df_lookup`:

```
             Name        Category
0          AMAZON          Amazon
1            AMZN          Amazon
2       Shell Oil             Gas
3  GOOGLE 5555555  Needs Category
```

With this code you iterate over `df_lookup` for each row in `df1` so it could not be the most efficient method with lots of categories in `df_lookup`

Comment: Thank you, that is great! A follow-up question to that. If I assign "Needs Category" to return if a category is not found. Is there a way to append the df_lookup to include those rows with the df1['Description'] and df1['Cateogry'] (which in this case would be "Needs Category")

Comment: @bbalch I've edited the function to also append the category not found

Comment: This has worked very well. After using this for a little bit I wanted to get your thoughts on an additional enhancement. This currently does a lookup based on the [‘Name’] and returns the corresponding [‘Category’]. Is there a way to modify this so that it does a lookup based on the [‘Name’] AND [‘Account’]? Assuming the [‘Account’] column is added to both the df1 and df_lookup DataFrames. @99_m4n

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. It makes a `Series` that contains sets with all the matching categories (empty if none are matching, or with multiple values if there are multiple matches).  There is an explicit loop, but it is on the lookup table (presumably much smaller than `df1`, the DataFrame to categorize):

```py
result = pd.Series([set()] * len(df1), index=df1.index, name='Categories')
dstr = df1['Description'].str
for k, name in df_lookup.set_index('Category')['Name'].items():
    idx = dstr.contains(name)
    result.loc[idx] = result.loc[idx].apply(lambda s: s|{k})
```

You could assign this to a new column of `df1`, or use it in any way you like.

On your example:

```py
>>> df1.assign(categories=result)
                     Description  Amount categories
0  AMAZON.COM*ajlja09ja AMZN.COM      10   {Amazon}
1          AMZN Mktp US *ajlkadf      15   {Amazon}
2           AMZN Prime *an9adjah      20   {Amazon}
3           Shell Oil 4106541031      20      {Gas}
4           Shell Oil 4163046510      25      {Gas}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great!

Comment: sure; it should be the fastest solution so far, if `df1` is larger than `df_lookup` (because the Python loop is on the latter, not the former). It also handles both cases where you may have 0 match or more than 1 match.