# How to assign/add columns from one data frame to another which contains duplicate values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1:

```
     id  value1 value2
 0   A_1  123   878
 1   A_2  251   356
 2   A_3  222   332
```

and df2:

```
    id
0   A_2
1   A_3
2   A_3
3   A_1
4   A_1
5   A_4
```

desired output:

```
    id   value1 value2
0   A_2    251      356
1   A_3    222      332
2   A_3    222      332
3   A_1    123      878
4   A_1    123      878
5   A_4    NA        NA
```

is there any fastest way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question ?:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907426/credit-card-transaction-classification-in-python?noredirect=1#comment120028270_67907426

Comment: `df2.merge(df1,on='id',how='left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a left-join:

```
df2.merge(df1, on='id', how='left')
```

[See this blog post for more details](https://towardsdatascience.com/left-join-with-pandas-data-frames-in-python-c29c85089ba4), or [the official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging).